# ngModel on select not showing initial, default value

Tags: angular, select, ngmodel

I have following Angular code:

comp.html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedBanner" (change)="onBannerChange()">
                    <option *ngFor="let banner of banners" 
                    [ngValue]="banner">{{banner.BannerDesc}}</option>

                </select>
```

comp.ts

```
    public banners: any[] = [
        {BannerId: 1, BannerDesc: 'AAAA'},
        {BannerId: 2, BannerDesc: 'BBBB'},
        {BannerId: 3, BannerDesc: 'CCCC'},
        {BannerId: 4, BannerDesc: 'DDDD'},
    ];
    public selectedBanner: any = {BannerId: 3, BannerDesc: 'CCCC'};
    onBannerChange() {
        console.log(this.selectedBanner);
    }
```

However, on load, the select dropdown is always blank. Only when I change, it gets the value. How can I set the default value on load?

I am using angular 4.0.0

Comment: Angular cannot connect a separate object with no reference to the array. just in your oninit do: `this.selectedBanner = this.banners[2]` and in your component just declare `public selectedBanner = {}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you are going to face when trying to store the value in another service and then default it to that value when you load the app is that from angulars point of view they aren't pointing to the exact same object in memory.

You will need to slightly alter you ngOnInit method as follows.

1. Find the index of the object in the banner array that you have stored based on a key like BannerId.
2. After that you can then set the selected option using the same
   this.selectedBanner = this.banners[bannerIdIndex].

By doing this you will be able to get angular pointing to the correct object in the list you are using in your ngFor

Comment: perfect, exactly what i wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Makes so much sense but I needed to hear you say it, @jLee; worked like a charm.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
  public banners: any[];

  ngOnInit() {
     banners = [
        {BannerId: 1, BannerDesc: 'AAAA'},
        {BannerId: 2, BannerDesc: 'BBBB'},
        {BannerId: 3, BannerDesc: 'CCCC'},
        {BannerId: 4, BannerDesc: 'DDDD'},
    ];

 }
```

Use ngOnInit() for two main reasons:

To perform complex initializations shortly after construction.
To set up the component after Angular sets the input properties.

Answer (score 0):

Fine answers here, but just to throw in this as we found out that this `selectedBanner` would be a global variable. You can do it like jLee suggested, also you can simply use `find()`, where you would assign (create reference) the value from the array based on your object, so:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.selectedBanner = this.banners.find(x => 
       x.BannerId == this.selectedBanner.BannerId)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also important that initial value which you're assinging to `ngModel` variable should be a number.
If it is not a number then use `parseInt(value);`